# JavaScript HTML5: issue with drag-and-drop for a gmail-like upload interface

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload, drag-and-drop

A screenshot of my interface:

[image]

Each element of the tree is a `<li>` and a `<a>`.

Each folder is a dropzone for file-upload like the gmail upload drag-and-drop.

When I "drag enter" on a folder with a file from my machine, I add a style:

[image]

The code for this:

```
var dropZoneElement = document.getElementById($this.attr('id'));

dropZoneElement.addEventListener('dragenter', onDragEnter, false);
dropZoneElement.addEventListener('dragleave', onDragLeave, false);
dropZoneElement.addEventListener('drop', onDrop, false);

function onDragEnter(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  $this.addClass('gmail-like');
}

function onDragLeave(event) {...}
function onDrop(event) {...}
```

But the problem is that when I drag a link (`<a>`) on a folder (even the fake link `test` with no destination, see screenshot), the page add the style to upload (no upload, it's just visual):

[image]

- Why?
- Any idea to disable this?

I would like the style applies only when I drag-and-drop a file from my machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you need to check the `drag data item kind` and verify that is indeed a file and not something else. Also, you can disable the

Have a look at the [HTML5 draft](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/dnd.html#the-drag-data-item-kind) describing the drag&drop process. [This tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/a-drag-and-drop-planning-board-with-html5/) may also provide some help.

Finally, the [following SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037976/javascript-drag-and-drop-with-partial-preventdefault) question should give you some concrete hints.